# Play framework and javascript i18n

Tags: jquery, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I'm working with getting javascript localization to work my play 2.0 app using twitter bootstrap and jquery with Jquery UI. The localization I'm aiming at requires messages for the validation plugin, datepicker etc.

AFAIK this requires me to include a javascript file with the localized messages for the validation and setting the datepicker.regional['XX']. So I need to get the currently selected locale of the ones offered by the play application (configured in the application.conf file using the application.langs property), and use this in my template to include the correct localized file, something like this:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/i18n/messages_<locale>.js")"></script>
```

Is this the best/only solution? How can I get the currently selected locale from play framework?

Comment: Do you render your view with Java or Scala controller?

Comment: I use java on the controller, but my view use scala. I guess I need to use scala in my templates to include the correct javascript file...?

Comment: You can take a look at this small example I did. Internalization in Scala templates and JS files.

https://github.com/geremora/play2-i18n-sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked for controller cause Java passes `lang` and Scala does not, anyway, solution for you is:

```
<script 
src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/i18n/messages_" + lang().code + ".js")'></script>
```